# Manejo de Excepciones PHP

Tags: php, excepciones

Verán, necesito manejar unas excepciones en la lectura de un XML, sin embargo NO logro redirigir a mi función personalizada.
Tengo algo así:

```
function myHandler($errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline){
    switch ($errno) {
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_NOTICE:
            echo "Personalizado";
            return true;
        break;
    }
}

set_error_handler("myHandler",E_WARNING);
set_error_handler("myHandler",E_NOTICE);
try{
    $xmlaux = simplexml_load_string($cadenaxml);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error!";
}
restore_error_handler();
```

Sin embargo no logra entrar a la funcion **myHandler**

Y en el error log aparece

**mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string()**

Cómo podría cachar la excepción ?

Ya intenté también declarando ***E_USER_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING,E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR*** y aún así no logro manejar la excepción.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos lo que te sugiero es crear una clase de tu CustomException dicha clase debe heredar el try.."try{...}catch(CustomException $e){...}"

Answer (score 0):

Saludos tal como te comente debes crear una clase , es decir extender Exception, para lo cual te dejo un ejemplo básico:

**Situación**

Desea crear una excepción para validar correos:

```
<?php
class customException extends Exception {
  public function errorMessage() {
    //mensaje de error
    $errorMsg = 'Error en la linea '.$this->getLine().' in '.$this->getFile()
    .': <b>'.$this->getMessage().'</b> Direccion de correo no valida.';
    return $errorMsg;
  }
}

$email = "micorreo@example...com";

try {
  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
    // uso throw exception si el correo esta mal
    throw new customException($email);
  }
}catch (customException $e) {
  //muestra mi mensaje personalizado.
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

este es un pequeño ejemplo de como podrias crear un exception que se adapte a tus necesidades para mayor detalle te sugiero la documentación:

[Extending Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)

[Casos prácticos de uso](http://ralphschindler.com/2010/09/15/exception-best-practices-in-php-5-3)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Hola Diego, te agradezco tu respuesta.

Checaré lo que me comentas, por qué a como lo veo, es un poco más en cuestión de alcance.

Como si PHP ( o más bien, la clase Exception) no distinguiera el tipo de error, warning o notice

La clsae extenderá a Exception, pero de todos modos probaré creándola.
Te agradezco